How to move two screens back by using FlowNavigationBackEvent in lwc
I am using custom LWC footer for "Previous" and "Next" buttons in Screen flow. My requirement is on click of "Previous" button I have to go two screens back in flow. I tried following approaches but not working. Only one screen its going back.
handleBack(){
      if (this.availableActions.find((action) => action === "BACK")) {
        const navigateBackEvent = new FlowNavigationBackEvent();
        this.dispatchEvent(navigateBackEvent);
      }
    }

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

You can't.  the only thing i can think of is a custom button that moves you forward and you have a decision after the screen that loops you back two screens.
